# Java swing applications not rendering properly with VNC

Tags: java, swing, java-8, vnc

Swing applications show a blank window when launched on a VNC desktop with Java 8. I don't have this problem with `JRE 7` and non-swing applications (eg. Eclipse) runs properly with the same settings.

Are there some sort of default settings like 3D acceleration or something that have been enabled by default on `JRE 8` ? How does i disable it ?

Comment: For the record: the problem only occurs with Java 8. Tested with Java 9 and 11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a Linux system, I've found that using the `-Dsun.java2d.xrender=false` option solved the issue. I think that xrender is now enabled by default on Java 8.

System Properties for Java 2D can be found here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html

Answer (score 19):

TL;DR

- Java and glxgears expect a color depth of 24.
- Make sure that X and VNC are set to use a depth of 24 and not some other depth like 16 or 32.

Details:

I had blank Java windows in VNC too, but with Java 7 and Java 8, so it wasn't much of a surprise that disabling `xrender` didn't help me.  That probably makes it a gross violation of StackOverflow protocol to post this here, but I found my way here, so surely others will too.  `-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true` made the text visible, though the anti-aliasing was like something out of the 1980s with a messed up palette, but then I got spuriously transparent parts of windows, always the same parts, cleanly composited, so not like a driver bug.  Noticing that glxgears was also displaying with a neat transparent background, when it's opaque black on other systems, I found a thoughtful and informative bug report against "compton", [RGBA windows are always transparent #179](https://github.com/chjj/compton/issues/179).  Inspired to look at `xdpyinfo`, I found my VNC server was offering "visuals" of depth 32 only, ie visuals with 8 bits each of red, green and blue and eight bits of alpha.  It seems Java, and glxgears, want an opaque visual, so one of depth 24.  My normal :0 X server has that as its default.  For the -depth switch, `man Xtigervnc` says "Default is 24, other possible values are 8, 15, and 16 - anything else is likely to cause strange behaviour by applications", yet [Debian's provisional packaging](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=654924) for TigerVNC, specifically in `/etc/vnc.conf` and `/usr/bin/tigervncserver`, sets it to a default of 32.  `-depth 24` and suddenly everything was beautiful again, with translucency only where it was requested.  `xdpyinfo` revealed many "visuals" on offer, including depth 32.

Comment: I was having trouble running OWASP ZAP on a Kali box in a tigervnc session - the windows kept coming up empty. Editing /etc/vnc.conf to change the default depth from 32 to 24 fixed it. Thanks, Martin!

Comment: Thanks Martin! I invested half a day on this **** error. Your post saved me!

Comment: The same problem occurs in XRDP. Edit xrdp.ini (/etc/xrdp/rxrdp.ini) and include 'xserverbpp=24' into the [Xvnc] and [Xorg] configurations.

Comment: I'm a noobie. How do I change it in RHEL 7?  I'm not sure where tigervnc config file and xrdp config files are

Answer (score 3):

On Red Hat Enterprise Linux there were two settings in the /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini file:

uncommented:               serverbpp=24
changed existing item:     max_bpp=24

Comment: I had this issue with MPLABX ide/ipe also on fedora 32, it would load with a blank/white screen. After many weeks I came across this fix, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem today after upgrading JetBrains pycharm to the 2019.x.x version (tried several of them).

Unlike the above, I was configured for 16 bit depth on both the vnc client and server which resulted in a red window with no text displayed when I started the upgraded pycharm (older 2018 versions worked fine).

Switching both the client (remmina - edit the individual connection configuration) and the server (tigervncserver / Xtigervnc) to 24 bit depth solved the problem for me.

Comment: is it a question or what  ?